# ViewPagerIndicator not updating after setCurrentItem()

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to make an app for a local event to allow referees to quickly judge performance.  Right now, I'm using a view pager that will not allow them to advance the page without inputting the results necessary in the page.  I also have the page auto advance after they have input results.

I also have a ViewPagerIndicator (the line one) that doesn't update after `setCurrentItem()` is called.  I tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `setCurrentItem()`, but that didn't seem to help.

Page advancing code:

```
if(pager.getMaxPage()<pager.getCurrentItem()+1){
        pager.setMaxPage(pager.getCurrentItem()+1);
    }

    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem()+1);
    pager.getIndicator().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I extended viewpager to store it's indicator.

Edit: To be clear, if I comment out the above code, and allow it to advance by swiping at all times, the indicator updates fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, dumb mistake.  If anyone sees this and has this issue, set your onPageChange listener to your indicator, not the ViewPager itself.